# Best way to write function with 2 functions as parameters

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have the following piece of code :

```
import { loader } from '../public/main.js';


export async function loadData(url, dataName, parseRowMethod=(x) => x, onLoadCallback = defaultOnLoadCallBack){
    var dataOut = [];
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
        loader.load( url,
            function (data){
                dataOut = onLoadCallback(data, parseRowMethod);
                resolve();
            },
            function (xhr) {console.log( ('Loading '+dataName+' : ' + xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' )},
            function(err)  {console.error(err)}
        )
    );
    return dataOut;
}

function defaultOnLoadCallBack(data, parseRowMethod)
{
    const dataOut = [];
    for (let row of data.split('\n')){
        dataOut.push(parseRowMethod(row));
    }
    return dataOut;
}
```

Here, `loader` is an instance of `THREE.FileLoader`. The idea here is that I'm trying to parse some files with some stereotyped data, and some data files that don't follow this stereotype.
I then set some methods for parsing rows and the whole data loaded.
Here, `onLoadCallback` is calling `parseRowMethod` where both are arguments of `loadData`. My code is working perfectly the way I intend it to, but I get the feeling that writing code this way is ugly.

Can somebody experienced explain to me what is the best way of coding this function ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Has your code something to do with node.js? Please add an appropiate to your question. You can doing it by clicking on the edit link underneath your question.

Comment: I'm not using node.js here. I'm learning js on my own, with no senior dev to supervise me. I'm just asking to understand well what is the best javascript syntax writing.

Comment: @Reporter I think you forgot a word, I should add an appropriate tag, is that it ? Thank you for correcting my post.

Comment: Yes i forgot the word tag.

Comment: @Reporter I see you've added the `three.js` tag for me, thanks a lot :)